# Stepwise variable selection, significance and interpretations

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, p-value, interpretation, stepwise-regression

I have read that the p-values of the variables resulting from a stepwise regression are smaller than it should be.

So, suppose there are two independent individuals trying to address some problem.

Individual 1: Have access to a large database. So decided to use a stepwise variable selection.

Individual 2: Have access to subset of the variables in the database. Decided to manually fit a model based on his experience.

What would happen if both of them end up with the same set of variables? Are these p-values reliable?

What would happen, if it happened to be the true model?

Can we interpret the regression coefficients after a variable selection?

Comment: They will not end up with the same variables, and stepwise variable selection has a probability of virtually zero of finding the right variables.

Comment: Thanks. Is it meaningful to interpret the coefficients after a variable selection? Because I have come across some toy example datasets where important variables getting omitted from the regression.

Comment: Not very meaningful.  They are biased and their standard errors are even more biased.  Please find a better approach then ask about that.

Answer (score -1):

It appears to be a multiple testing problem involved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem

If you estimate the model coefficients more then one time (whether doing an automatic job or manually) the alpha that you use to filter out significantly different from zero coefficients after looking at t-test's p-values should be adjusted to the number of hypothesis checks done.

If one searches over millions of possible models, including many different variables and their combinations, chances are one will pick a model with low p-values that arise out of the sample fluctuations.

In order to select a variable (model) in case of multiple possible alternatives use the adjusted alpha.